# Subscript operator overload of a class with a vector of Base classes that has to return Derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, overloading

So, the question might be a little bit confusing, but let me explain.

I have a class that contains 3 other classes and a vector. 2 of the 3 classes inherit from the third one and the vector is filled with shared_ptr

```
class top_class
{
     class Base
     {};

     class Derived1 : public Base
     {};

     class Derived2 : public Base
     {};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> my_vector;
};
```

I would like to make a subscript operator overload that returns a reference to Derived1 or Derived2, depending on the type of the element that I have been asked for.

I have been trying to use auto, but I'm pretty new to c++11 and I don't quite get it to work.

Please bear in mind that I have been asked to deliver it in such a way that the user should call the subscript operator like this:

```
top_class tc;
Derived1 d1 = tc[ 0 ];
Derived2 d2 = tc[ 1 ];
```

So using templated functions would not be a solution. My current attempt is this:

```
auto operator[](int index) -> decltype(*my_vector[index])
{
    return *my_vector[index];
}
```

But of course this does not work as the type that I'm passing to decltype is Base.

Comment: What do you want to happen on `Derived1 d1 = tc[ 0 ];` if `my_vector[0]` is really a `Derived2`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe what you're really after is a variant type.

Comment: I am being asked to throw an exception in that case, which makes me think that I actually need to know the type of d1... But that does not seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since return types in C++ are compile-time specified, the somewhat unusual syntax

```
top_class tc;
Derived1 d1 = tc[ 0 ];
Derived2 d2 = tc[ 1 ];
```

is hard to implement (much simpler would be something like

```
Derived1 d1 = tc.get<Derived1>(0);
Derived2 d2 = tc.get<Derived2>(1);
```

when `top_class::get<>` knows what to return). With the original syntax, `top_class::operator[]` must return something that can be converted to either `Derived1` or `Derived2`. As far as I can see, the only possibility is a `Base`, if both `Derived1` and `Derived2` allow for construction from `Base`:

```
struct top_class
{
  struct Base { /* ... */ };
  struct Derived1 : Base
  {
    Derived1(Base const&);
    // ...
  };
  struct Derived2 : Base
  {
     Derived2(Base const&);
    // ...
  };
  Base const&operator[](std::size_t i) const
  {
    return *(data.at(i));
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> data;
};
```

Comment: The construction thingy seems to be working just fine! Thanks! And now that I think about it, it kinda makes sense :D

Comment: I did actually upvote it, but it seems I am not allowed to do so or something like that since my reputation is below 15. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a variable type based on some runtime state. What you can do is ask the user to provide what type he wants and use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

```
template <class Derived>
std::shared_ptr<Derived> get(size_t idx) const
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(my_vector[idx]);
}
```

If you want this to throw, you can check if the result is null and throw as appropriate:

```
template <class Derived>
std::shared_ptr<Derived> get(size_t idx) const
{
    auto res = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(my_vector[idx]);
    if (!res) throw ...;
    return res;
}
```

At which point, we might as well also use `vector::at()` to throw there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given the member variable

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> my_vector;
```

you cannot get an object of a derived type from it without performing dynamic cast.

As soon as you introduce dynamic cast, you will need to account for failure of dynamic cast. At that point, you have to take into account the following factors in your design/implementation.

1. When dynamic cast fails, do you want to throw an exception, or do you want to return something that is equivalent to a `nullptr`?
2. How do you want to invoke the function? The derived type must be passed as a template parameter. If you choose to use `operator[]`, you will need to invoke it with

   ```
   auto ret = obj.operator[]<DerivedType>(index);
   ```

   That syntax looks pretty ugly to me. Maybe something like `std::vector::at` will be more appropriate.

   ```
   auto ret = obj.at<DerivedType>(index);
   ```

   In either case, the return type of the function will depend on how you want to deal with failure.

If you choose to throw an exception, you'll need something like:

```
template <typename DerivedType>
DerivedType& at(size_t index)
{
   std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = my_vector.at(index);
   dynamic_cast* derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<DerivedType>(ptr.get());
   if ( derived_ptr == nullptr )
   {
      throw std::bad_cast();
   }
   return *derived_ptr;
}
```

If you choose to return a `nullptr` when dynamic cast fails, you'll need something like:

```
template <typename DerivedType>
DerivedType* at(size_t index)
{
   std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = my_vector.at(index);
   return dynamic_cast<DerivedType>(ptr.get());
}
```

Please note that `std::vector::at` will throw an exception if `index` is out of range.

Comment: So are you saying that the invokation syntax like the one mentioned in the OP is not possible?

Comment: @Cruelo, that is correct. The template parameter cannot be derived from the argument(s). Hence, it must be explicitly specified in the call.